# Copying latest file from remote server

Tags: files, scp, file-copy

There is a collection of `.doc` files, in addition to other types of files, on a remote server (which supports SCP).

I am trying to write a script to retrieve the latest (most recently modified) `.doc` file from the remote server. The path to my current working directory cannot be absolute since my script may be deployed in another server.

I am able to solve the problem partially in two steps:

1. Copy all the `.doc` files from the remote server to my local `~/Downloads` folder:

   ```
   scp -i key.pem abc@xyz:/tmp/*.doc ~/Downloads/
   ```
2. Select the latest file from `~/Downloads` and copy it to the required folder:

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads
   latest_file=$(ls -t *.doc | head -n 1)
   cp -p "$latest_file" /current working directory
   ```

How can I copy the latest `.doc` file present in the remote server xyz under the folder `/tmp` to my local machine in a single statement without downloading all of them into an intermediate folder?

Comment: Have you tried to use rsync to do this?

Comment: (1) I’ve made a rough guess at what you mean, and edited your question based on that guess.  If I damaged the meaning, please fix it.  (2) I don’t understand what you’re saying about your current working directory, either.  (3) When you’re using a deferred wildcard (e.g., a wildcard that you want to be expanded on a remote server), you should always enclose it in quotes; e.g., `scp -i key.pem "abc@xyz:/tmp/*.doc" ~/Downloads`.  It’s true that it will work without the quotes 99% of the time, but it you just get into the habit of using quotes all the time, you’ll be protected in that 100th case.

Comment: (1)Thanks for the edit. I have retained the edited version.

Comment: Current working directory is a normal folder within my file system. This is answered by shivams. by the usage of .

Comment: And yes, will use the quotes. Did not know about it. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not really clear what your problem is, but if you're trying to copy to the current directory then just use `.` to refer to the current directory so that your command is:

```
scp -i key.pem abc@xyz:/tmp/*.doc .
```

Comment: The dot (.) solved my problem of having the files copied to my local working directory. Thank you. One pending question now. How will I copy only the latest file from the remote location instead of the whole set of *.doc files

Answer (score 2):

Let's see if this will solve your problem.
Make a script.

```
FILE=`ssh abc@xyz ls -ht /tmp/*.doc | head -n 1`
rsync -avz -e ssh abc@xyz:"$FILE" .
```

This will run a command on the remote server "ls -ht /tmp/*.doc | head -n 1"
and will show the latest doc. Rsync that specified file from remote server to your current directory.
ssh/rsync will also ask you a password for the user "abc", better is to use a passwordless login or a keyfile "key.pem".

Comment: Note that the OP indicated that he was using a `key.pem` file in the question.